# Set UIButton's background as a CAGradientLayer

Tags: swift, xcode

How can I set the background of a UIButton to a CAGradientLayer?

I have tried the following:

```swift
func applyGradient(colors: [UIColor], locations: [NSNumber]?) -> Void {
    let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = self.bounds
    gradient.colors = colors.map { $0.cgColor }
    gradient.locations = locations
    self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
}
```

which I got from [Set Background Gradient on Button in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37903124/set-background-gradient-on-button-in-swift)

and then to use it:

```swift
let startButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("Get Started", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(AppSettings.PURPL_COLOR, for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Rubik-Medium", size: 16.0)
    return button
}()

startButton.applyGradient(colors: [.red, .blue], locations: nil)
```

Also, I am setting the width of the button to the view's width and the height to 50.

However, when I run it, this is what I get:

[image: result]

The background gradient is not applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bounds` of the button will be 0 when you call the method `applyGradient`. So create a UIButton subclass and change the gradient layer `frame` in `layoutSublayers` method

```
class GradientButton: UIButton {
    let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    internal override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    internal required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    required init(_ colors: [UIColor], locations: [NSNumber]?) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        applyGradient(colors,locations:locations)
    }
    func applyGradient(_ colors: [UIColor], locations: [NSNumber]?) {
        gradient.colors = colors
        gradient.locations = locations
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    }
    override func layoutSublayers(of layer: CALayer) {
        super.layoutSublayers(of: layer)
        gradient.frame = self.bounds
    }
}
```

And create the button with color and location values

```
let button = GradientButton([.red,.blue], locations: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'd rather use UIButton only. Would applying the gradient in viewDidLayoutSubviews be fine?

Comment: @OmarHashim Yes. Call `startButton.applyGradient(colors: [.red, .blue], locations: nil)` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: @OmarSinan But `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method is called multiple times in a view controller. Every time you call `applyGradient` method it adds a new layer. Consider using `UIButton` subclass or keep a reference to the `gradientLayer`

Comment: Oh right I did not think of that. Thanks for the heads up!