# how do i set the background color of UIViews to be a gradient color in swift?

Tags: swift, uiview, cagradientlayer

Im trying to set the color of my button and labels to a gradient color in swift with the following code:

```
extension UIView {

    func setGradientColor(colorOne: UIColor, colorTwo: UIColor) {

        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = [colorOne.cgColor, colorTwo.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0,0.1]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)

        layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
   }
}
```

and then in the sign in form i use the extension like this:

```
let logo: UILabel = {
    let logo = UILabel()
    logo.text = "Logo"
    logo.setGradientColor(colorOne: UIColor.blue, colorTwo: UIColor.yellow)
    logo.textAlignment = .center
    logo.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 59)
    return logo
}()
```

but it still shows up as black.
how do i fix this?

Comment: This might help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37903124/set-background-gradient-on-button-in-swift

Comment: where are you adding constraints ? or frame ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set Background Gradient on Button in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37903124/set-background-gradient-on-button-in-swift)

Answer (score 1):

What you posted i review that ... call `setGradietColor(colorOne: UIColor.blue, colorTwo: UIColor.yellow)` after setting the frame or constraints to the logo view

You can add gradient layer in your view

```
let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

        gradient.colors = [UIColor.black.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor]
        gradient.locations = [0.0 , 1.0]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x : 0.0, y : 0)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x :0.0, y: 0.5) // you need to play with 0.15 to adjust gradient vertically
        gradient.frame = view.bounds
        view.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're facing this issue because you're not updating the `frame` of `gradientLayer` when `bounds` of `logo` updates. For example in ViewController you can give this code if you can have the reference to your `gradientLayer`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var gradient: CAGradientLayer?

    let logo: UILabel = {
        let logo = UILabel()
        logo.text = "Logo"
        gradient = logo.setGradietColor(colorOne: UIColor.blue, colorTwo: UIColor.yellow)
        logo.textAlignment = .center
        logo.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 59)
        return logo
    }()

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        gradient?.frame = logo.bounds
    }
}
```

Try returning the `layer` from your method and modify your function like this:

```
extension UIView {

    @discardableResult
    func setGradietColor(colorOne: UIColor, colorTwo: UIColor) {

        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = [colorOne.cgColor, colorTwo.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0,0.1]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)

        layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
        return layer
   }
}
```