# Why is the linear gradient not fully applied to ios button

Tags: ios, button, linear-gradients

I am using the following code to apply a linear gradient to an iOs Button

```
 private func applyGradient(colors: [CGColor])
{
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = colors
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    gradientLayer.frame = self.addToCart.bounds 
    self.addToCart.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
}
```

However the gradient is not fully applied to the button. Here is an image of the ios Button

[image]

Comment: Is this Swift, Objective-C, or React-Native and Expo?

Comment: This is in swift

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37243106/15422011 Check this out

Comment: It doesnot work for me

Comment: Most likely the frame is changing later. Try modifying the frame of gradientLayer inside `layoutSubviews` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: Exactly that what I did thank you. Dou you want to write it as an answer so I can tick it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, `viewDidLoad` for view controllers or `init` for custom views is too early for gradient frames. Also, their frames will most likely change later on, which you need to handle.

If you are applying a gradient to a custom view, try updating its frame inside `layoutSubviews()` (from this great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58384141/14351818)).

```
class GradientButton: UIButton {

    /// update inside layoutSubviews
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
    }

    private lazy var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = {
        let l = CAGradientLayer()
        l.frame = self.bounds
        l.colors = [UIColor.systemYellow.cgColor, UIColor.systemPink.cgColor]
        l.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
        l.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: )
        layer.insertSublayer(l, at: 0)
        return l
    }()
}
```

For a view in a view controller, try `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var addToCart: UIButton!
    var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer? /// keep a reference to the gradient layer so we can update its frame later  
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        /// still first make the gradient inside viewDidLoad
        applyGradient(colors: [UIColor.systemYellow.cgColor, UIColor.systemPink.cgColor])
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        /// update here!
        self.gradientLayer?.frame = self.addToCart.bounds 
    }  

    private func applyGradient(colors: [CGColor]) {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = colors
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        gradientLayer.frame = self.addToCart.bounds 
        self.addToCart.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)

        self.gradientLayer = gradientLayer
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a button subclass with gradient, you probably should just update the gradient `frame` in the [`layoutSubviews`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews) of this subclass rather than the view controller’s `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: @Rob yep, good point. Also voted for your answer

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to manually updating the `frame` of the gradient layer is to declare the button’s [`layerClass`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622626-layerclass) to be a `CAGradientLayer`:

```swift
@IBDesignable
public class GradientButton: UIButton {
    public override class var layerClass: AnyClass         { CAGradientLayer.self }
    private var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer             { layer as! CAGradientLayer }

    @IBInspectable public var startColor: UIColor = .white { didSet { updateColors() } }
    @IBInspectable public var endColor: UIColor = .red     { didSet { updateColors() } }

    // init methods

    public override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        updateColors()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        updateColors()
    }
}

private extension GradientButton {
    func updateColors() {
        gradientLayer.colors = [startColor.cgColor, endColor.cgColor]
    }
}
```

This achieves the behavior of the proposed solution, but also:

- Unlike the manual setting of the gradient layer’s `frame` in the view controller’s `viewDidLayoutSubviews` (or, better, the button’s `layoutSubviews`), this will respond to animated layout changes more gracefully. If an animation of the button’s `frame` is underway (e.g. rotating the device or what have you), this `layerClass` approach will render the button correctly mid-animation. The manual setting of the gradient layer’s `frame` won’t.

  [image]
- It is not necessary, but I have made this `@IBDesignable`, so should you add this button in IB, you can adjust the colors and the `startPoint`/`endPoint` right in Interface Builder, seeing it rendered realtime.

  [image]

  Here I made the gradient diagonal, changed the colors, and added a border, all from Interface Builder using this expanded rendition of the above.

  ```swift
  @IBDesignable
  public class GradientButton: UIButton {
      public override class var layerClass: AnyClass         { CAGradientLayer.self }
      private var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer             { layer as! CAGradientLayer }

      @IBInspectable public var startColor: UIColor = .white { didSet { updateColors() } }
      @IBInspectable public var endColor: UIColor = .red     { didSet { updateColors() } }

      // expose startPoint and endPoint to IB

      @IBInspectable public var startPoint: CGPoint {
          get { gradientLayer.startPoint }
          set { gradientLayer.startPoint = newValue }
      }

      @IBInspectable public var endPoint: CGPoint {
          get { gradientLayer.endPoint }
          set { gradientLayer.endPoint = newValue }
      }

      // while we're at it, let's expose a few more layer properties so we can easily adjust them in IB

      @IBInspectable public var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
          get { layer.cornerRadius }
          set { layer.cornerRadius = newValue }
      }

      @IBInspectable public var borderWidth: CGFloat {
          get { layer.borderWidth }
          set { layer.borderWidth = newValue }
      }

      @IBInspectable public var borderColor: UIColor? {
          get { layer.borderColor.flatMap { UIColor(cgColor: $0) } }
          set { layer.borderColor = newValue?.cgColor }
      }

      // init methods

      public override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
          super.init(frame: frame)
          updateColors()
      }

      required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
          super.init(coder: coder)
          updateColors()
      }
  }

  private extension GradientButton {
      func updateColors() {
          gradientLayer.colors = [startColor.cgColor, endColor.cgColor]
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing these two lines:

```
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
```

With this one line:

```
gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
```